# Let V be the $\mathbb R$-vector space of the continuous functions in the interval [0, 1]...

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Let V be the $\mathbb R$-vector space of the continuous functions in the interval [0, 1], and S : V $ \to \mathbb R$ defined by S(f) := $\int^1_0$ f(t)dt.

> a-) Show that S is a linear transformation.

> b-) Is it injective?

> c-) S is surjective?

a-) $T(cf + g) = \int^1_0 (cf(t) + g(t)) dt = c\int^1_0 f(t) dt + \int^1_0 g(t) dt = cT(f) + T(g)$

b-) $x_1 \neq x_2 \to \int^1_0 x_1 dx = \frac {x_1^2}{2} \neq \frac {x_2^2}{2} = \int^1_0 x_2 dx $.

c-)$f(x) = y = \int^1_0 f(x) dx = \frac {x_n^2}{2} = y_n \forall n \in [0,1]$.

Are the answers good enough?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Can’t you have two different functions in $V$ that have the same definite integral?

Comment: IMO, b) and c) are wrong. Injectivity was only proved for a specific function. Moreover, a definite integral doesn't have the +C.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner two integrals are equal, then the functions are the same, right?

Comment: @Gab:  no; consider $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=\frac12$

Answer (score 3):

Part (a) is fine. Parts (b) and (c) have serious issues, which suggest to me that you don't understand $T$.

$T$ takes a continuous function defined on $[0, 1]$ (these are the elements of $V$) and maps them to their definite integrals from $0$ to $1$. Definite integrals of real functions are real numbers, which is why the codomain is the set of real numbers.

Let's cover some examples, just to get a feel for this linear map. Take the function $f(t) = t^3$. Then
$$T(f) = \int_0^1 f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^1 t^3 \, \mathrm{d}t = \left[\frac{t^4}{4}\right]_0^1 = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{0}{4} = \frac{1}{4}.$$
So the function $f$, a vector in $V$, maps to the real number $\frac{1}{4}$. Note that there's no constant of integration (which there isn't when dealing with *definite* integrals), nor does a dependent variable appear in the expression, such as $t$, $x$, or $x_1$, or anything like that.

Another example just to hit it home: the exponential function $\exp(x) = e^x$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ (and everywhere else) so it is a vector in $V$ too. We have
$$T(\exp) = \int_0^1 \exp(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^1 e^t \, \mathrm{d}t = \left[e^t\right]_0^1 = e^1 - e^0 = e - 1.$$

Let's concentrate on (c) first. To say $T$ is surjective is to say that *every* real number is the definite integral of some continuous function on $[0, 1]$. Is this true? Could you, for example, find a function $f(t)$ so that $\int_0^1 f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t$ is equal to, say, $5$? What about $-6\pi$? Are there any numbers that you couldn't do this for? I would recommend thinking about what $T$ does to constant functions. For example, if $h(t) = 2$, what is $T(h)$? What if $h(t) = e$? I'll let you think about this for yourself.

Now, what about (b)? To say $T$ is injective is to say that no two functions in $V$ produce exactly the same definite integral. So, in our above example $f$, we calculated an integral of $1/4$. Are there any other functions out there that *also* have an integral of $1/4$? Once again, the constant functions may help you out here.

I'll let you think about this for yourself, because that is the best way to learn. Let me know with a comment if you're still struggling.

Comment: if $h(t) = 2$ then $T(h) = \int_0^1 h(t) = \int_0^1 2 = t^2$, for $e$ would  be $ex$?

Comment: If $h(t) = 2$ then $T(h) = \int_{0}^{1}2 = 2t \bigr|_{0}^{1} = 2-0 = 2$ not $t^2$.

Comment: thanks @eng2math that was a big mistake

Comment: @Gab I agree with eng2math. Once again, you should not have $T(h)$ be a function of the variable $t$. Note that, in the case of $T(\exp)$, $e$ is a constant. If you are considering constant functions in the form $h(t) = a$, where $a$ is a fixed constant, then $T(h)$ can only depend on $a$ (not on $t$), because we get different functions $h$ depending on the value of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Part a) is good.

The linear transformation is not an injection, a counterexample would be $f_1(x) = x^2$ and $f_2(x) =\frac{2}{3}x$ will have the same definite integral on the range $[0,1]$.

For surjectivity, let $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then the constant function $f(x) = y$ will have integral $\int_{0}^{1} y dx = yx \bigr|_{0}^{1} = y$, so the map is surjective.